# subresources problem with dependencies in JAVA

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, cdi

When I created my subresource, my Injection (authenticatedUser) is null. But in the root class (authenticatedUser) the Injection had the correct values. Therefore, when I used

> /medicos/me

I get the correct values, but when I used

> /medicos/me/pacientes

I get a error null, from authenticatedUser in subresource PacienteResource.
I don't understand and how I can resolve this dependency in sub resource. This dependency (authenticatedUser) is produced in authentification filter.

```
@Path("/medicos")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MedicoResource {

    @Inject
    @AuthenticatedUser
    Usuario authenticatedUser;

    @GET
    @Path("me")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response getMedico() {
        return Response.ok(authenticatedUser.getMedico().getNombre()).build();
    }

    @Path("/me/pacientes")
    public PacienteResource getMedicoPacientes() {
        System.out.println("get medico pacientes");
        return new PacienteResource();//This is the problem.
    }
}
```

Subresource class also had the authenticatedUser, but when I used it, this is null.

```
public class PacienteResource {

    @Inject
    @AuthenticatedUser
    private Usuario authenticatedUser;

    @Inject
    PacienteService pacienteService;

    @GET
    @RolesAllowed({"MEDICO"})
    public Set<Paciente> getPacientes() {
        Set<Paciente> pacientes = authenticatedUser.getMedico().getPacienteSet();
        return pacientes;
    }
}
```

This is my producer of @AuthenticatedUser. The filter "Authentification"throw a event, for this Observer "handleAuthenticationEvent". Then when I need a authenticatedUser I only should inject a @AuthenticatedUser. But when I created the new instance of pacienteResource, the AuthenticatedUser is not produced.

```
@RequestScoped
public class AuthenticatedUserProducer {   

    @Inject
    private UsuarioService usuarioService;

    private Usuario authenticatedUser;

    public void handleAuthenticationEvent(@Observes @AuthenticatedUser String username) {
        this.authenticatedUser = findUser(username);
    }

    private Usuario findUser(String username) {
        Usuario usuario = usuarioService.findByUserName(username);
        return usuario;
    }

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    @AuthenticatedUser
    public Usuario createLogger() {
        return authenticatedUser;
    }
}

@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface AuthenticatedUser {

}
```

Comment: Q: Any chance you can reproduce the problem with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  Q: What's your development/runtime environment (e.g. Eclipse? Tomcat?  Jersey? Spring Boot?)

Comment: JAX-RS and my server is WildFly

Comment: Interesting - I didn't know JBoss had a new home (Redhat, now IBM) and a new name (WilldFly).  SUGGESTION: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40225429/cdi-weld-se-not-injecting-inner-dependencies-when-using-producer-method

Comment: But I have a producer for authenticatedUser, the problem is when here "return new PacienteResource();" the new object is not created with authenticatedUser, the producer is not producing an authenticatedUser.

Comment: Q: Short of you writing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please do, if you can!), how can we reproduce the problem to help you resolve it?

Comment: Try to inject [`ResourceContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceContext.html)  into the parent resource and use `rc.getResource()` to create the resource instead of manually instantiating it.

Comment: As an aside, your sub resource classes should NOT be annotated with `@Path`. If you have classpath scanning enabled, then it will register the sub resource class as a root resource class (which you do not want).

Comment: @paulsm4 I added more code of my problem! And I deleted Path of my subresource.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion in my previous comment?

Comment: I found the solution, injecting the subresource in the root resource.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in this way: I inject the object instead of creating a new instance in runtime. I do not understand very well how this work, but this works.

```
@Path("/medicos")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MedicoResource {

    @Inject//Injection instead of create a new instance.
    PacienteResource pacienteResource;

    @Inject
    @AuthenticatedUser
    Usuario authenticatedUser;

    @GET
    @Path("me")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response getMedico() {
        return Response.ok(authenticatedUser.getMedico().getNombre()).build();
    }

    @Path("/me/pacientes")
    public PacienteResource getMedicoPacientes() {
        return PacienteResource;// Problem solved.
    }
}
```